# Log in using java jsoup doesn't work

Tags: java, authentication, jsoup, scraper

After trying out different tutorials and reading lots of posts here I still can't manage to login to a website using jsoup.

This is my code

```
        Connection.Response response =  Jsoup.connect("https://www.ivolatility.com/login.j")
                .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                .execute();

        response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ivolatility.com/login.j")
                .data("username", username)
                .data("password", password)
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                .execute();

        Document homePage = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ivolatility.com/options.j")
                .cookies(response.cookies())
                .get();
```

Comment: Shouldn't you use `https` in your last request? You used `http://www.ivolatility.com/options.j`, I would firstly check `https` URL here.

Comment: I did. Same result. Seems like this website works like this. To log in they use https and after you are logged in it disappears.

Answer (score 2):

Check the `post` request that the **browser** sends (use your browser's developer tools) - it sends some extra parameters that you don't send. Add them to your reauest:

```
response = Jsoup.connect("https://www.ivolatility.com/login.j")
            .data("username", username)                
            .data("ref_url", "")
            .data("service_name", "")
            .data("step", "1")
            .data("login__is__sent", "1")
            .data("password", password) 
            .cookies(response.cookies())
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();
```

It will also be wise to add the `user agent` string of your browser to the request, since your program may send its own string, resulting in a total different response from the browser.

Comment: That was the solution. Thanks.